# Somehow adding to "Insert Into URL" posts are contradicting each other

Tags: plugins, php, wp-insert-post

I added a second upload image ( doc_thumb_box ). They both work perfectly independent of each other. But when the second one is added, the first one (doc_uri_box ) no longer pastes the value of the URL into the box. Instead **both** boxes, if there is any content in them, become *blank*.

Is there something obvious that is contradicting the other?

```
public static function doc_thumb_box() {
global $post;

$thumb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'upload_image', true );

function my_admin_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
}

function my_admin_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_styles');
}

echo 'Enter a URL or upload an image for the thumb.';
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
echo '<label for="upload_image">';
echo '<input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value=" ' . $thumb . '" />';
echo '<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Thumb" />';


echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
</script>\r\n";

}

public static function doc_uri_box() {
    global $post;

    $uri = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpa_upload_doc', true );
    echo "<style type=\"text/css\">
#edit-slug-box {
display: none;
}

</style>";
   echo '<p>Please provide the abosulte url of the file (including the <code>http://</code>):</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="wpa_upload_doc" name="wpa_upload_doc" value="' . $uri . '" size="25" style="width:85%" />';
    echo '<input class="button" id="upload_doc_button" type="button" value="Upload Publication" alt="Upload Publication" />';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#upload_doc_button').click(function() {
    formfield = jQuery('#wpa_upload_doc').attr('name');     
    tb_show('Upload Publication', 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=1&width=640&height=263');
    return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    var docurl = jQuery(html).attr('href');
    jQuery('#wpa_upload_doc').val(docurl);
    tb_remove();
}
});
</script>\r\n";
}
```

**UPDATE**

For the `doc_uri_box()` method, I have found that the `window.send_to_editor` code block is never executed! Strange indeed..

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had a few unecessary variables in here.

1. I didn't need to define `formfield` as a var because it's unused. I defined it twice.
2. Because there are two functions sharing common variables, it's best that I nest the `window.send_to_editor` within each of the click functions.

**This is the final version of both the jQuery functions ( the source of the problem)**

```
jQuery('#upload_doc_button').live('click', function() {

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        var docurl = jQuery(html).attr('href');
      jQuery('#wpa_upload_doc').val(docurl);
        tb_remove();
    }

    tb_show('Upload Publication', 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=1&width=640&height=263');
    return false;
}); 


jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {

 window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
  imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
  jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
  tb_remove();
 }

 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});
```